# Block this spammer

Tags: support, spam

This one has answered/commented two questions, both with spam.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12373/clavier-arabe
I suggest blocking this user by admin.

Comment: Thanks; he's gone.

Answer (score 1):

@[MPD](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd) has been already taken care of the spammer.

For future reference about what to do when you see a spam post, see [What should I do when I see spam posts?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1077/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-spam-posts)

Most importantly, don't edit a spam post to remove the spam content; that just makes harder to identify the spam.